# Coldfusion cfhtmltopdf tag not displaying bmp images

Tags: coldfusion, bmp, coldfusion-11

I'm using a `<cfhtmltopdf>` tag to pull in a .cfm file as a template and create a PDF. All works well when I use jpg for the image format. But if the image is a BMP - for some reason it won't work.
In the template file , I'm using a `<cfdirectory>` tag with no filter to pull in the images.

```
<cfdirectory directory="E:\xxx\images\#image_ID#\" name="myDir" type="file" sort="datelastmodified">
```

then I'm using a `<cfloop>` to display images from the directory...

```
 <cfloop query="myDir">
  <cfif right(myDirMain.name,4) is ".bmp" >

        <img src="#request.root#images/#images_ID#/#myDir.name#" border="0" width="230px" style="margin-bottom:15px;"  />
      </cfif>
```

This works great for jpg, but when trying to use bmp images - it's no good.

Does anyone know if a reason why bmp images are an issue or does  only work with jpg images?

Comment: What do you mean by the statement "_but when trying to use bmp images - it's no good_"? Is the code skipping over the `<img>` tag? Does the image not look "good" in the browser? Is an error being thrown?

Comment: Hi, I get a missing image icon in the PDF that is created where there should be an image. Thanks

Comment: Can you include your `<cfhtmltopdf ...` code?

Comment: sure, here you go...    `<cfset temppath="#uploadPath#pdf">
<cfhtmltopdf pagetype="a4" destination="#temppath#/#id_refid#.pdf" overwrite="Yes" orientation = "portrait">
<cfinclude template="../includes/pdf_a4_template.cfm">
</cfhtmltopdf>`

Comment: Is the URL you are using for the image href (`#request.root#images/#images_ID#/#myDir.name#`) accessible from the ColdFusion (PDF) server? Meaning, can you open a browser on the ColdFusion (PDF) server and see the bitmap image?

Comment: Hi, after spending one time on this, it looks like its a bug in Coldfusion - its meant to do it, but sadly can't. So I have gone down the route of converting any BMP images that are used before adding them to a PDF using the <cfimage tag.

Comment: Did you file a bug report (or find an existing one)? If so, go ahead and add it to your answer so it is more visible and other folks can vote on it.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bug in the system that stops PDF's using BMP images. A solution is to convert them using `<cfimage>` tag before creating the PDF - its workaround that works, even thou it uses a little bit more server resources.